# compare values of cells in different rows in table using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a dynamically generated table with php that has same rows. Need to get value from cell 1 in row 1 and value from cell 1 in row 2 and compare them. If they are the same remove entire row or hide... Do that for the whole table... Any help is appreciated.. Thanks!!

Haave this so far:

```
var numRows = $('table#changeSubjectKatedra tr').lenght;
var i = 0;
do {
    var cur = $('input#'+i).val();
    var next = $('input#'+(i+1)).val();
    if(cur == next){
        $('tr#'+i).remove();
        }
    i++;
} while(i<numRows);
```

The row in table looks like this:

```
<tr id='idNum'><td>someText<input type='hidden' value='someData' id='idNum'>
</td><td>someText</td></tr>
```

Comment: Fyi, IDs cannot start with a number unless you are using HTML5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note 1. You should do in on server side with PHP, not with JavaScript.

Note 2. You must use unique id for each element.

Note 3. Avoid using numerical ids of elements.

Note 4. You don't need ids at all for doing what you want.

If you still want to do it in JavaScript, I suggest you to do it this way: ([live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/riateche/2AvKa/))

```
var rows = $("#changeSubjectKatedra tr");
for(var i = 0; i <= rows.length - 2; i++) {
  if ($(rows[i]).find("input").val() ==
      $(rows[i+1]).find("input").val()) {
    $(rows[i]).remove();   
  }
}
```

Comment: Because it's simplier and will work without JavaScript. And while page is loading, all rows will be shown, and some lines will be hidden only after page is loaded. And it is just more beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's .each function. This should work according to the description you provided:

```
$('table#changeSubjectKatedra tr').each(function() {
    if (repeat == $(this).children("input")[0].value) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
    repeat = $(this).children("input")[0].value;
});
```