# Compare values of cells in different rows in table using PHP

Tags: php, html-table

My question is similar to the one found here:

[compare values of cells in different rows in table using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570554/compare-values-of-cells-in-different-rows-in-table-using-jquery)

Using PHP, what is the best way to group together rows and cells - if the value in the first column and the value of the 3rd columns are the the same, while maintaining the zebra-stripe pattern?

This is what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/zmcjwqk9/

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>TITLE A</td>
        <td>TITLE B</td>
        <td>TITLE C</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: yellow">
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: red">
        <td>AA</td>
        <td>BB</td>
        <td>CC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: yellow">
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: yellow">
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>BBBB</td>
        <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: red">
        <td>AA</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>CC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: yellow">
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: red">
        <td>AA</td>
        <td>BB</td>
        <td>CC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: red">
        <td>AA</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>CC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: yellow">
        <td>AAAA</td>
        <td>BBBB</td>
        <td>CCCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: yellow">
        <td>AAAA</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>CCCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: yellow">
        <td>AAAA</td>
        <td>BB</td>
        <td>CCCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: red">
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>CC</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**PHP**

```
 echo '<table class="tableListingTable">
            <thead style="font-size: 2.5em; height: 40px; line-height: 40px; width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td>To</td>
                    <td>Time</td>
                    <td>Airline</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';

    foreach ($productPages as $productArray => $v) {
        $class = ($c = !$c) ? 'odd' : 'even';
        echo '<tr class="future ' . $class . '">';
            echo '<td width="16%">' . $v['destinationCity'] . '</td>\n';
            echo '<td width="16%">' . $v['currentTime'] . '</td>\n';
            echo '<td width="16%">' . $v["airlineName"] .'</td>';}
        echo '</tr></tbody></table>';
```

Comment: Are you talking about doing this in the PHP script that creates the table, or is the PHP script downloading the HTML and parsing it with a DOM parser?

Comment: I have the PHP creating the table rows and cells already. The part I'm having issue with is comparing the rows > values in column A and column B. If the values match, give it a certain color.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Are you trying to do this grouping in the script that creates the table, or in another script that reads the table (similar to the way jQuery processes the result)?

Comment: Oh sorry - in the script that creates the table

Comment: Then please show the code that creates the table. You should do the grouping there. Or you could do it in the database query, so it doesn't return duplicate rows.

Comment: Have you seen the `TableIterator` [by @hakre](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2012/02/28/some-php-iterator-fun/) yet? It's available on Github [as Gist](https://gist.github.com/hakre/1930284) as well. Simply define your callback for the `FetchIterator` and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that creates the table should be something like this:

```
$color = 'red';
$prevA = $prevC = null;
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if ($row['A'] != $prevA || $row['C'] != $prevC) {
        $color = $color == 'red' : 'yellow';
        $prevA = $row['A'];
        $prevC = $row['C'];
    }
    echo "<tr class='$color'><td>{$row['A']}</td><td>{$row['B']}</td><td>{$row['C']}</td></tr>";
}
```